# bottom margin or padding doesn't work in relative layout in xml on android

Tags: android, imageview, padding, margin

I have a `RelativeLayout` for a row that goes inside a `ListView`. The row looks like,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/placeDetailIcon_Img"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" 
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I also tried it with margin:

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/placeDetailIcon_Img" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
```

Neither apply the margin or padding around the `ImageView`. How do create this type of spacing?

Comment: RelativeLayout `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`?

Comment: And also get rid of the `RelativeLayout` if your list items are going to be represented by just one view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use this its work with me :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">  

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView1"
         android:layout_width="50dp"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: why does android:layout_marginTop work and android:paddingTop does not?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who is looking for a solution to this - from the docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

"Note that you cannot have a circular dependency between the size of the RelativeLayout and the position of its children. For example, you cannot have a RelativeLayout whose height is set to WRAP_CONTENT and a child set to ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM."

It seems also that there is some odd behavior if you put a relativeView inside of a scrollview.

In my case I had set the relativeLayout to wrap_content and then tried to add marginBottom to an ImageView with the ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM attribute. When I set the height explicitly it finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use LinearLayout... Or you can try to remove the attribute: `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`

If you want to center the view in a RelativeLayout you can use:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

Comment: android:layout_centerInParent="true" does both of those in one go :)