# Floating Action Button with drawer is not working

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawer, floating-action-button

My Floating Action Button is not working with the drawer. I'm not able to click on a button and also not able to set it's position. I tried the same code in other .xml file without a drawer and it was working perfectly.

I also tried with the `<FrameLayout></FrameLayout>` but still no luck. I am using API 23. Any suggestions??

My file..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.dipen.transporter.MyPostActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/myFAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp_1x"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/primaryBlue"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: why both have same id's??

Comment: @VivekMishra: I accidentally pasted twice in here..sorry for that.

Comment: what exactly is not working? Is button not shown or click event not working?

Comment: @VivekMishra :click is not working and it's not positioning properly..

Comment: add a screenshot for position

Comment: are you using [CooridnatorLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html)?

Comment: @snachmsm : Nope.. RelativeLayout

Comment: check out [some implementations](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout), this layout might help you. If not post more code (with drawer lines) and screenshot might be helpful also

Comment: @snachmsm  :added screenshot..

Comment: @VivekMishra: added screenshot.

Comment: increase marginBottom for positioning

Comment: @VivekMishra : Also tried that..

Comment: why your relative layout is match_parent?

Comment: You having problem only with relative layout?Does your code work with other layout?

Comment: margins not working in `Relativelayout` childs, checkout [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237210/bottom-margin-or-padding-doesnt-work-in-relative-layout-in-xml-on-android), but you can't use code from answer. implement `CoorinatorLayout` - it's well working with FAB and other Material design widgets

Comment: @snachmsm: I'm more concern about the click..

Comment: show how you attach `OnClickListener`